# Assign Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE) MAC Address

Tags: bluetooth, mac-address

I'll like to know if Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE) devices are assign MAC address according to [company-identifiers](https://www.bluetooth.org/en-us/specification/assigned-numbers/company-identifiers) document or is that more of a suggestion to follow?

In the document Core_V4.0.pdf in section `1.2 BLUETOOTH DEVICE ADDRESSING` it explain about how the address is made up of `company_assigned` and `company_id`, is it like WIFI MAC address that are assigned to each company or I just need to make sure the address I generate are unique?

Comment: BLE interfaces have two addresses: one that is unique and assigned by vendor, so it is guaranteed to be unique around the world; and another that is random, to protect privacy.

Comment: Thank you, can you post a link to documentation that explain and this in more details please